# Partial merge in doctrine?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

In a system I'm developing, I send a whole form through AJAX to the system's logic. The form allows me to update a bunch of data related to a single class, however, I don't have the need to update all the attributes of the class, only a part of it. Everything works fine until I have to persist the data. When I do the following:

```
$entityManager->merge($entity);
```

I get an error stating that NULL fields are not allowed in the database, which apparently means that when I do such an operation the whole class updates all of its fields. That's because the system maps the data sent from the form to an object using only the incoming data.

So, my question: how can I update only the incoming data and nothing else, using a similar syntax to the one stated before and not building an `UPDATE` query? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Why are you using merge? Merge is usually used for detached entities.

Comment: When the system's logic receives the data, it creates a new object with the incoming data. So, the entity remains detached.

Comment: Has anyone resolved this issue? @user1231958, any luck?

Comment: I couldn't solve it. After a lot of struggling I decided to use Symfony as my framework since it comes bundled with Doctrine2, and it works.